# BeautifulSoup text outside of tags

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to grab all of Kramer's lines from every episode of Seinfled on this site:

http://www.imsdb.com/TV/Seinfeld.html

I've already pulled the list of episode names into a file I labeled episode-list.txt

I'm trying now to just parse the lines after **KRAMER** but they seem to be outside of the tags, which is where I'm stumped. See here --> http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Seinfeld-Good-News,-Bad-News.html

Below is the code I'm trying to run using BeautifulSoup. Any clues would be much appreciated. Also, any unsolicited advice is hereby solicited haha. If you see anything I'm doing that strikes you as clunky or brutish coding, I'd love the feedback.

Cheers!

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

text = open ("episode-list.txt","r")


for line in text.readlines():
    url = "http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Seinfeld-" + line.strip('\n').replace(" ", "-") + ".html"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    for tag in soup:
            print soup.findAll('???')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code snippet to serve as a reference to get you started...

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<b>                             KRAMER
</b>               (enters) Are you up?

<b>               
</b><b>                             JERRY
</b>               (To Kramer) Yeah...(in the phone) Yeah, 
               people do move! Have you ever seen the 
               big trucks out on the street? Yeah, 
               no problem (hangs up the phone).
<b> 
</b><b>               
</b><b>                             KRAMER
</b>               Boy, the Mets blew it tonight, huh?
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for kramer in soup.find_all('b', text=re.compile("\s+KRAMER\s+")):
    print kramer.next_sibling.strip()
```

output will be...

```
(enters) Are you up?
Boy, the Mets blew it tonight, huh?
```